# How to trim IP Address to get the first 3 parts of it?

Tags: c#, string, trim

I need to trim a given IP Address to get the first 3 parts of it

**Example:**

"192.168.1.20"  ➨  "192.168.1."
"29.6.60.241"   ➨  "29.6.60."

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, your alias precedes your comments :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`String result = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("."));`

Comment: thanks :)
String result = input.substring(0,input.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".";

Answer (score 5):

Using [String.LastIndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx), it should be easy.

**EDIT**
Using that method you can locate the last '.'. Then you need a substring up to and (apparently) incuding that '.'. Something like:

```
string shortened = longIP.Substring(0,longIP.LastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

Comment: If he needs to include the `.`, then should that be `lastIndexOf` + 1?

Answer (score 2):

```
string ip= "192.168.1.100";
string partial = ip.Substring(0,ip.LastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string sHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ipE = Dns.GetHostByName(sHostName);
IPAddress[] IpA = ipE.AddressList;
for (int i = 0; i < IpA.Length; i++)
{
    if(IpA[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} {2} ", i, IpA[i].ToString() , sHostName);
        string[] x = IpA[i].ToString().Split('.');
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}.", x[0], x[1], x[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment yea you right i forgot about it.. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Internally, IP addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) are just bit strings.  IPv4 fits into 32 bits and IPv6 fits into 64 bits.  So the real answer to your question is to just mask the bits you want to keep using a logical AND operation and have the others be 0.

In most situations you get to specify an IP address together with a mask.  The rule is that to ask if A is the same as B, you check the bits for which the mask bit is true.

This leads to a common notation: people write an IP address like 124.51.3/17 to say that the first part describes an IP address (maybe IPv4) and that the /17 means that the first 17 bits are the ones to consider.